# SMTP Mail attachment in ASP.NET

Tags: smtp, sendmail

My project requirement is to send emails to clients with .pdf files as attachments. I do that successfully and my question is about the filename of the file I am sending. It attaches the whole path of the file to the filename and that doesn't look professional at all. How can I change this behavior?

My code is:

```
  try
                {   string filename = "C:/MailFiles/Client-" + person.ToString() + ".pdf";
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
                    {
                        var attachment = new Attachment(filename);
                        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                        client.Send(mail);

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Found the solution. attachment.Name property.